# how to print a list with use for loop in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

```
ids = (['1', '020021', 'AAA'],
['2', '070031', 'BBB'],
['3', '519601', 'CCC'],
['4', '110021', 'DDD'])

for x,y,z in ids:
    print(x,y,z)
```

How to write that use one line? below throw exception.

```
print('\n'.join(*ids))
```

Comment: You want to join list, but string type expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this does not work is twofold:

1. `'\n'.join` accepts only **one** argument: an iterable of strings;
2. the objects you provide are no **strings**, but lists, so the `join` function does not know what to do with these.

You need to format every line yourself then, with `'{} {} {}.format(..)`:

```
print('\n'.join('{} {} {}'.format(*idi) for idi in ids))
```

So we iterate over the `idi`s of `ids`, and then for each such line, we add `'{} {} {}'.format(*idi)` to the result, and join these then together with a new line.

This produces:

```
>>> print('\n'.join('{} {} {}'.format(*idi) for idi in ids))
1 020021 AAA
2 070031 BBB
3 519601 CCC
4 110021 DDD
```

In case the number of "columns" is arbitrary, we can also use `join` instead of a format string:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(idij) for idij in idi) for idi in ids))
```